# substitute A for B

Tags: prepositions, discourse-context

This is from "Artificial Intelligence For Dummies"

> Mistruths of commission are those that reflect an outright attempt to
> **substitute truthful information for untruthful information**. For
> example, when filling out an accident report, someone could state that
> the sun momentarily blinded them, making it impossible to see someone
> they hit. In reality, perhaps the person was distracted by something
> else or wasn’t actually thinking about driving (possibly considering a
> nice dinner). If no one can disprove this theory, the person might get
> by with a lesser charge. However, the point is that the data would
> also be contaminated. The effect is that now an insurance company
> would base premiums on errant data.

I think the phrase in bold should be corrected to 'substitute untruthful information for truthful information' in the above context.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cited text uses the wrong preposition...

> *Mistruths of commission are those that reflect an outright attempt to substitute truthful information <strike>for</strike> **with** untruthful information.*

But ***substitute*** is a slightly awkward word to use here - there would be less scope for confusion with ***replace, displace, overwrite,*** etc.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you could also use "substituted by". There are a lot of similar questions on [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/601023/is-it-substitute-by-or-substitute-for-by).

Comment: @StuartF: As pointed out, ***replace*** is less problematic than ***substitute*** when it comes to distinguishing initial / final state on the basis of the preposition. But [as my answer to a related ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151309/) shows, there's an "unexpected" usage preference between active *Someone replaced A **by / with** B* and passive *A was replaced **by / with** B*.